# linux compilation error by using make

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

i got the error when i try to 'make' the linux kernel 3.12.9

HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:462:1: fatal error: opening dependency file scripts/basic/.fixdep.d: Permission denied

}
 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make[1]:**  [scripts_basic] Error 2
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated’: Permission denied
make[1]:  **No rule to make target `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by`arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: I see `Permission denied` everywhere. Try adding `sudo` e.g. `sudo make myProgram`

Comment: you probably need to use `fakeroot`

Comment: iirc the tool i used to build a kernel did forbid me to compile it as root.

Comment: i am compling linux  and when i write                                                 "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12.9-31209$ make" on terminal   this give me the error

Comment: Asu fake root not working .IIRC is difficult to get online i want solution in short time

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to build in a directory that you do not own and do not have permission to write in.  You should probably be performing an out-of-source build.

Comment: If you want to perform an out-of-source build by hand, as opposed to via whatever kernel-building tools are provided by your distro, you could try this: (1) create a build directory within your home directory, e.g. `/home/furqan/kernel`, and make that your working directory.  (2) Run `make` via this command: `make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12.9-31209/Makefile VPATH=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12.9-31209`.

Comment: Note also that demanding quick responses ("i want solution in short time") is rarely well received on SO.

Comment: no solution yet .Please help me out this is not my kernel i installed it from the internet so basically the problem is when i compiled it by getting in the directory and linux-headers-3.12.9-031209 i got a error same as above when i use "sudo make"

Comment: Try asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/